# Authorize.net ios Sdk error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am facing issues while testing with the Test Accunt.

i had entered correct user name and password with transaction key..

i had used below code for login..

[AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];

```
MobileDeviceLoginRequest *mobileDeviceLoginRequest =[MobileDeviceLoginRequest mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = @"xxxx";
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey =@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.sessionToken =sessionToken;
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"xxxxxxx";
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];

AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance]; 
[an setDelegate:self];
[an mobileDeviceLoginRequest: mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
```

but returning below xml on a responce.

`ErrorE00003The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'mobileDeviceId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.`

can anyone had idea to solve this error...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass the `transactionkey` when your are registering. just pass `loginid` and `password`

Comment: its only used with the Testing but what abt realtime test.

Comment: For real-time testing you need yo have a live account.

Comment: does apple allow  payment transaction using Authorize.net.They dont reject?

Comment: @FirstTimer yes they allow.One of my app is already on app store

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine but when run with xcode 3.2.5 and with device getting error like AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance]; an=null...so what should I have to do for the same??

application is crashing at [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST]; in xcode 3.2.5 in device.