# How to test Authorize.net in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, authorize.net

I am using [Authorize.net](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios)

and device registered successfully but `getTransactionDetailsSucceeded` is not called?

how can I test it..

`namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"`

Also followed this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308377/authorize-net-ios-sdk-error) but still no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response .. But its already done...

```
//Call this method at once in project
-(void)registerDevice
{
    NSLog(@"registerDevice");
    MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest *registrationRequest=[MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];

    registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name= txtUserName.text;

    registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = txtPassword.text;

    registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDescription=@"iPhone";
    registrationRequest.mobileDevice.phoneNumber = @"7889999999";
    registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDeviceId=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
                                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"]; 
    NSLog(@"registrationRequest %@",registrationRequest);
    [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];

    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

    [an setDelegate:self];

    [an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:registrationRequest];

}


//And after above method call below method

- (void) loginToGateway {
      MobileDeviceLoginRequest *mobileDeviceLoginRequest =
        [MobileDeviceLoginRequest mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
      mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = txtUserName.text;
      mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = txtPassword.text;
      mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
        [[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];

      AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

      [an setDelegate:self];
      [an mobileDeviceLoginRequest: mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
}
```

Comment: Its working fine but value of [AuthNet getInstance] getting in xcode 3.2.5 and run with device..!!

Comment: what is the use of transaction key if we only need to use password which is not safe?

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when ur device is not registered.So write above method to register your device and replace it with ur credentials

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, Error Message.code = E00059
Message.text = The authentication type is not allowed for this method call.

solution is--If your device is already registered
               then comment the below code

```
[an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
```

This is for the Registration device